# How to get different condition on same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get different condition on same table?

I'm joining the same table again, but I think is bad idea.

TableA:

| Id | Name | Gender | PositionNo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Andy | 1 | 500 |
| 2 | Jason | 1 | 510 |
| 3 | Alma | 2 | 520 |
| 4 | Annie | 2 | 510 |

TableB:

| Id | KeyNo | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | boy |
| 2 | 2 | girl |
| 3 | 500 | Principal |
| 4 | 510 | Student |
| 5 | 520 | Teacher |

My SQL code:

```
SELECT 
    a.Name,
    b.Value AS GenderName,
    c.Value AS PositionName
FROM 
    TableA AS A
LEFT JOIN 
    TableB AS B ON A.Gender = B.KeyNo
LEFT JOIN 
    TableB AS C ON A.PositionNo = B.KeyNo
```

Result

| Name | GenderName | PositionName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Andy | boy | Principal |
| Jason | boy | Student |
| Alma | girl | Teacher |
| Annie | girl | Student |

Do you have any idea how I can do it better?

Comment: No other way, although you may want to have multiple different tables with each type of reference data depending on your real use case i.e. in this example, Gender and Position info could be 2 separate tables

Comment: How do you measure "better"?

Comment: I'm not sure ,
I thought have other way No need to query twice

Comment: Don't worry about querying data twice. You write down query logic, SQL server decides, how to get data. Your logic seems correct - that's all what matters.

Comment: You suffer from [one table to rule them all](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58372/is-the-one-description-table-to-rule-them-all-approach-good). But no matter, a "lookup" is required for each value, doesn't really matter where. Eventually someone will accidentally assign 500 to Gender because you cannot constrain it.

Comment: Yeah, as the SMor stated you suffer from transitive dependency. You just need to divide your B table into pieces like sex_table and jobs_table. In order to make it better, please check 3NF(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: Thanks all Ans, I get it. Because it was Old Project so I can't  change it.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried this but i contain duplicates

```
select name ,post,value from tabA t1
inner join tabB t2 on t2.keyno=t1.postitionNo
or
gender=keyno
```

output
alam    520 girl
alam    520 teacher
andy    500 boy
andy    500 principle
annie   510 girl
annie   510 student
jason   510 boy
jason   510 student

Comment: Not really an improvement on OP's own solution